# Django admin: separate querysets for changelist_view and change_view

Tags: python, django

In my app I need to hide some elements (with flag deleted=True) in change list in Django admin panel (I have it using custom queryset) but be able to show them using change_view (to edit individual items). Now if I set up custom queryset it is not possible to display an item (there is 404 error). Is there a convenient way to have separate query sets for different views?
I made some testing with passing request parameters and based on it use different querysets but it looks a bit ugly.

UPD: Here is how I solve this issue now: http://pastebin.com/5VqArNSi. Looking for something better.

Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you showed some code. How are you setting up a custom queryset?

Comment: @Alasdair, I added paste to my question.

Comment: Here's an approach that might work, don't know whether it's much better than what you already have: override `get_object` (used by the change view), and use `super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_queryset()`, or maybe even `MyModel.objects.all()`. Then, you can override `get_queryset` without if statements.